# Wrong RPMforge Installed

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, centos-6

I am running CentOS 6.2 and I installed RPMforge EL5 by mistake and I need to uninstall it and install RPMforge for EL6. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. To remove I did this:

```
yum remove rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64
```

And to add the new repo for EL6 I downloaded it then did this:

```
rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, `yum remove rpmforge-release*`